# How to write a custom factory attribute without using the generate function

Tags: python, factory, factory-boy

I currently have the code:

```
class QuerySuggestion(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = dict

    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def query(self) -> str:
        word = factory.Faker("word")
        return f'<span>{word.generate({"locale": "en"})}</span> {word.generate({"locale": "en"})}'
```

Which works great apart from the fact that the maintainer said [not to use the `generate()` function](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/787#issuecomment-703503593).

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to go through `class Params`:

```py
class QuerySuggestion(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = dict

    class Params:
        word1 = factory.Faker('word')
        word2 = factory.Faker('word')

    query = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: f"<span>{o.word1}</span> {o.word2}"
    )
```